# How to do hibernate mapping to mysql server through ssh tunnel?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ssh-tunnel

I have to implement one java class, that will read data from mysql server. I am able to connect to mysql server through mysqlyog using ssh tunneling option. But when I tried it through code I am getting JDBCConnectioException: Error calling Driver#connect.

Here is my hibernate mapping file:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        username
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        username
    </property>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a local instance of MySQL listening at port 3306?

Comment: I found the solution, First we have to create the ssh tunnel Using jcsh, then bind your local port 3306 to server port 3306.